# Building Azure Multi-Factor Authentication into Custom Apps (SDK)

Tags: azure, multi-factor-authentication

We have SSO IdP in house with local AD. We also have Azure subscription.

I want integrate our IdP with Azure MFA. I thought I could use
approach Building Multi-Factor Authentication into Custom Apps (SDK) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-sdk
however there is info that it has been deprecated.

So what I would like to achieve is:

- authn happens on premise (SSO IDP)
- if successful then call Azure MFA as a second factor

Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Azure's Multi-Factor Authentication server is an on-premise component that has a Web Service SDK, which is not deprecated. I think you need to use this SDK in order to implement your requirements. It's WSDL is available on a similar URL:

https://yourdomain.com/MultiFactorAuthWebServiceSdk/PfWsSdk.asmx?WSDL